# How to use findIndex with strings and objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I use findIndex when I have a array of strings or objects. Both of the above code returns -1

```
console.log(['kk', 'll', 'mm', 'pp'].findIndex(function(x) { x == 'mm'}))
console.log([{name: 'kk'},{name: 'vv'},{name: 'mm'},{name: 'ok'}].findIndex(function(x) { x.name == 'mm'}))
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xrLf92p/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return the result of the condition so [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) knows if the value was found or not

```
['kk', 'll', 'mm', 'pp'].findIndex(function(x) { return x == 'mm'})
```

It should be noted that used like this, with an array of just strings, `indexOf` works just fine

```
['kk', 'll', 'mm', 'pp'].indexOf('mm')
```

but for an array of objects, as in the second example, it's very useful to have a callback

```
[
    {name: 'kk'},
    {name: 'vv'},
    {name: 'mm'},
    {name: 'ok'}
].findIndex(function(x) { 
    return x.name == 'mm';
});
```